# python sys.path ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_name' when importing in Docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, containers, sys.path

I am attempting to run a Docker container, but I am encountering the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basic_config'" when trying to import the module "basic_config" from the config directory. Although the code runs without any issues on Windows and Linux servers, the error only occurs when running the code inside a base Docker container. I am seeking a solution to resolve this issue and be able to import the module correctly within the Docker container.

this is the file structure

```
"""
    ml-project/
        enviroment/
            env.dev
            env.prod
        src/
            config/
                base_config.py
            model/
                model1/
                    model.py
            .env
        piplines.yml
        requirements.txt
    """
```

this this model.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../config")
from basic_config import AGE

print(AGE)
```

this is the docker file

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ARG env_type=dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "src/module/model1/model.py"]
```

Comment: You have a `base_config` but no `basic_config` in your file structure.

Comment: config/base_config.py

Comment: this script works on windows and linux

Comment: Therefore `No module named 'basic_config'"` is perfectly normal...

Answer (score 1):

I change the working directory to the module's directory before executing the Python script and it works. Here's the updated Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ARG env_type=dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/src/module/model1
CMD ["python", "model.py"]
```